# Scala (Spray/Akka) : The request content was malformed: an implementation is missing

Tags: json, scala, akka, spray

I have a problem using Spray to get the post body:

When I send in a Json call I get "The request content was malformed: an implementation is missing"

The Json I send is the Json created in the request (val test)
As mentioned in the code I got the implementation from [Providing a JsonFormat for a Sequence of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756836/providing-a-jsonformat-for-a-sequence-of-objects)

**CreateOrder.Scala**

```
import spray.json._
import spray.httpx.unmarshalling._
import spray.httpx.marshalling._


case class CreateOrder (order_number: String,
                        order_source_code: String,
                        created_order_date: String,
                        shipping_address: String,
                        payment_method: String,
                        customer_name: String,
                        customer_tel: String,
                        customer_postcode: String,
                        customer_email: String,
                        ob_zone: String,
                        order_line_items: Seq[Order_Line_Items]
                        )
case class Order_Line_Items (order_line_item_number: String,
                                           sku_number: String,
                                           item_name: String,
                                           paid_price: String
                                          )

//Source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756836/providing-a-jsonformat-for-a-sequence-of-objects
object CreateOrderProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
   implicit object OrderItemsFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Order_Line_Items] {
    def write(oli: Order_Line_Items) = JsObject(Map(
      "order_line_item_number" -> JsString(oli.order_line_item_number),
      "sku_number" -> JsNumber(oli.sku_number),
      "item_name" -> JsString(oli.item_name),
      "paid_price" -> JsString(oli.paid_price)
    ))
    def read(value: JsValue): Order_Line_Items = ???
  }
  implicit object CreateOrderFormat extends RootJsonFormat[CreateOrder] {
    def write(order: CreateOrder) = JsObject(Map(
      "order_number" -> JsString(order.order_number),
      "order_source_code" -> JsString(order.order_source_code),
      "created_order_date" -> JsString(order.created_order_date),
      "shipping_address" -> JsString(order.shipping_address),
      "payment_method" -> JsString(order.payment_method),
      "customer_name" -> JsString(order.customer_name),
      "customer_postcode" -> JsString(order.customer_postcode),
      "customer_email" -> JsString(order.customer_email),
      "ob_zone" -> JsString(order.ob_zone),
      "order_line_items" -> JsArray(order.order_line_items.map(_.toJson).toList)
    ))
    def read(value: JsValue): CreateOrder = ???
  }
}
```

**Main.Scala**

```
path("dev" / "order" / "create") {
        headerValueByName("AppId") { appId =>
          headerValueByName("AppSecret") { appSecret =>
            post {
            entity(as[CreateOrder]){ req =>
                respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
                  complete{
                     val test = new CreateOrder("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10",Seq( new Order_Line_Items("11","12","13","14"), new Order_Line_Items("21","22","23","24") ) )
                    if(elasticCaller.api_check(appId,appSecret)){
                        val reply = Map("Status"->"Success")
                        ModelConverter.fromAnyToJson(test)
                    }else{
                        val reply = Map("Status"->"Failed")
                        ModelConverter.fromAnyToJson(test)
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
object CreateOrderProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport {

  implicit val OrderLineItemsFormat = jsonFormat(Order_Line_Items, "order_line_item_number", "sku_number", "item_name", "paid_price")
  implicit val OrderItemsFormat = jsonFormat(CreateOrder, "order_number", "order_source_code", "created_order_date",
    "shipping_address", "payment_method", "customer_name", "customer_tel", "customer_postcode", "customer_email",
    "ob_zone", "order_line_items")

}
```

from: [Spray-json deserializing nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691525/spray-json-deserializing-nested-object)